# Why has changed both sides of equation in java?

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka

I have a strange problem that confused me completely.

I am using WEKA for my project, and I want to change class values of my dataset to test somethings; so I preserve my dataset into another value whose name is **d**, and using setClassValue method for changing class values. Finally, I print classValues for each instance in d and dataset variables.

```
Instances d=dataset;
for (int i = 0; i <dataset.size(); i++) {
    dataset.get(i).setClassValue(10);
    System.out.println(dataset.get(i).classValue()+ "\t" +d.get(i).classValue() );
}
```

Result is not believable, **both d and dataset class values were changed.** Why did this happen? How can I change class values of a dataset with considering that I should preserve my original dataset?

Comment: Read the comments in SLaks' answer.  I also suggest reading [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28Java_method%29) and referring to [shallow copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shallow_copy#Shallow_copy) vs [deep copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_copy#Deep_copy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d=dataset
```

You now have two variables that both refer to the **same** object.

Unlike C++, Java never implicitly copies anything.
If you want a separate copy of an object, you need to make one yourself.

If the object implements `Cloneable`, you can do that using `clone()`.

Comment: Clone does not guarantee a deep copy. Cloning and then using .setXX methods could very well change values for both original and clone. Cloneable in Java is terrible. :( My suggestion: write a copy-constructor and make sure that it really copies everything (you will run into problems here too, if the underlying objects also are not easily copied).

Comment: Java copies the variable - it's just that the variable is a reference, not the object itself.

Comment: @Xabster Yes, the default `.clone()` may return a shallow copy, but one can modify it s.t. it returns a deep copy.  Using a standard copy constructor may also return a shallow copy...